# how to access autogenerateSelectButton in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

if i make autogenerateSelectButton as true then it display the select button in all rows of grid. but i want to access that "select" so i have to write code for that which i have done in which there is common functionality of all the select but i want to access that particular row which is selected by user. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to detect that user has selected a row? If that is the case, listen to the GridView:s (I assume GridView since it is a grid in ASP.NET), listen to the SelectedIndexChanged event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx